# How to add in the array an element toggled as active?

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this page a bunch of buttons (anchor element) has it own number (id), I have to select them and put into an array when they are toggled as active.
I've already created an array, the id from buttons are adding and they are all being printed, but I can't use this class ".active" instead of my normal class "btn_reservas".

How can I add / remove in my array only the selected numbers?

```js
 
 var controller = (function () {
  var ctrlAddItem = function (event) {
    console.log("It worked, pressed id  = " + event.target.id);
    event.target.classList.toggle("active");
 };

  document.querySelectorAll(".btn_reservas").forEach(function () {
    this.addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);
  });

  document.addEventListener("keypress", function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
      ctrlAddItem();
    }
  });  

var sum = 0;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_reservas");
  // var x = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_reservas.active");
  var numbers = [];
  for (i=0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].id;
    numbers.push(', ' + x[i].id);
  }

  numbers.forEach(myFunction);

  function myFunction(item) {
    sum += item;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sum;
  }
})();
```

```css
body {
    background-color: #ffffff;
  }
  
  h1 {
    color: #999999;
    align-content: center;
    padding-left: 400px;
  }
  
  #menu {
    background-color: #4682b4;
    padding: 3px;
  }
  
  #menu ul {
    text-align: center;
    padding-left: 20%;
    list-style: none;
  }
  
  #menu ul li {
    display: inline;
  }
  
  #menu ul li a {
    color: #ffffff;
  
    /* padding-left: 5%; */
    margin: 50px;
    background-color: #4682b4;
    font-size: xx-large;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
  
  #menu ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
  }
  
  #Promocoes {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
  }
  
  #Promocoes img {
    align-content: center;
    padding: 25px;
  }
  
  #item {
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    background-color: rgba(9, 50, 99, 0.35);
  }
  
  #item p {
    font-size: 14px;
  }
  
  #item button {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #item button:hover {
    background-color: #b0c4de;
  }
  
  /* Sobre Nos */
  
  
  
  #historia {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  #historia img {
    padding-left: 100px;
    align-self: center;
  }
  
  /* SORTEIO */
  
  .legenda ul li{
    list-style: none;
    
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bolder;
    margin-right: 1%;
    margin-top: 5px; 
    margin-bottom: 10px; 
  }
  
  .disponivel {
    cursor: default;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px #a9a9a9 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
  
  }
  
  .reservados {
    cursor: not-allowed; 
    background-color: lightgreen;  
    border: 2px green solid;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
  
  }
  
  .pagos {
    cursor: not-allowed; 
    background-color: lightsalmon;
    border: 2px indianred solid;
    color: #ffffff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
  
  }
  
  .enviar {
    background-color: #4682b4;
    cursor: pointer; 
    color: #ffffff;
    border: #4682b4 solid;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 8px;
  
  }
  
  .lista_sorteio {
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  
  
  
  .lista ul li {
      display: inline;
  
  }
  
  .lista ul li a {
    display: block;
    border: 2px solid #bfc0bf;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 40px;
    max-width: 75px;
    height: auto;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 20px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color:rgb(85, 161, 108);
    border-color: #212529;
    margin-right: 50px;
  }
  
  .btn {
      display: inline-block;
      font-weight: 400;
      color: #212529;
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      cursor: pointer;
      -webkit-user-select: none;
      user-select: none;
      background-color: transparent;
      border: 1px solid transparent;
      padding: .375rem .75rem;
      font-size: 1rem;
      line-height: 1.5;
      border-radius: .25rem;
      transition: color .15s ease-in-out,background-color .15s ease-in-out,border-color .15s ease-in-out,box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
  
  }
  
  .lista ul li a:hover {
    color: #212529;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    font:bolder;
    transition: all 600ms ease;
  
  }
  
  .lista ul li a.active {
    background-color: #f90;
  }
```

```html
<div class="lista">
        <ul >
            <li>
                <a href="#000" id="000" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">001</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#001" id="001" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">002</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#002" id="002" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">003</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#003" id="003" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">004</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#004" id="004" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">005</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#005" id="005" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">006</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#006" id="006" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">007</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#007" id="007" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">008</a>        
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#008" id="008" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">009</a>        
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div> 
</div>

<hr>

<p>Get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<hr>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still refer to `.btn_reservas.active` you just have to use `querySelectorAll` instead of `getElementsByClassName`.

This will still calculate sum, but it doesn't worry about the array as it just looks for elements with `.btn_reservas.active`.

```js
var controller = (function() {

  function calcSum(){
     toggled = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_reservas.active");
     sel =[];
     
     toggled.forEach(function(el){
        sel.push(el.getAttribute("id"));
     });
     
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = sel.join(", ");
  }

  var ctrlAddItem = function(event) {
    console.log("It worked, pressed id  = " + event.target.id);
    event.target.classList.toggle("active");
    calcSum();
  };

  document.querySelectorAll(".btn_reservas").forEach(function() {
    this.addEventListener("click", ctrlAddItem);
  });

  document.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13 || event.which === 13) {
      ctrlAddItem();
    }
  });
})();
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

h1 {
  color: #999999;
  align-content: center;
  padding-left: 400px;
}

#menu {
  background-color: #4682b4;
  padding: 3px;
}

#menu ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 20%;
  list-style: none;
}

#menu ul li {
  display: inline;
}

#menu ul li a {
  color: #ffffff;
  /* padding-left: 5%; */
  margin: 50px;
  background-color: #4682b4;
  font-size: xx-large;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
}

#Promocoes {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

#Promocoes img {
  align-content: center;
  padding: 25px;
}

#item {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: rgba(9, 50, 99, 0.35);
}

#item p {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#item button {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

#item button:hover {
  background-color: #b0c4de;
}


/* Sobre Nos */

#historia {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#historia img {
  padding-left: 100px;
  align-self: center;
}


/* SORTEIO */

.legenda ul li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: bolder;
  margin-right: 1%;
  margin-top: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.disponivel {
  cursor: default;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 2px #a9a9a9 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.reservados {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  border: 2px green solid;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.pagos {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  background-color: lightsalmon;
  border: 2px indianred solid;
  color: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.enviar {
  background-color: #4682b4;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: #4682b4 solid;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.lista_sorteio {
  margin-left: 200px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.lista ul li {
  display: inline;
}

.lista ul li a {
  display: block;
  border: 2px solid #bfc0bf;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 40px;
  max-width: 75px;
  height: auto;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: rgb(85, 161, 108);
  border-color: #212529;
  margin-right: 50px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #212529;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  padding: .375rem .75rem;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
  border-radius: .25rem;
  transition: color .15s ease-in-out, background-color .15s ease-in-out, border-color .15s ease-in-out, box-shadow .15s ease-in-out;
}

.lista ul li a:hover {
  color: #212529;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  font: bolder;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}

.lista ul li a.active {
  background-color: #f90;
}
```

```html
<div class="lista">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#000" id="000" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">001</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#001" id="001" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">002</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#002" id="002" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">003</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#003" id="003" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">004</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#004" id="004" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">005</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#005" id="005" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">006</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#006" id="006" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">007</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#007" id="007" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">008</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#008" id="008" class="btn_reservas" data-original-title="Número 001 Pago por: Pedro">009</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>

<hr>

<p>Get the sum of the numbers in the array.</p>

<p id="demo"></p>

<hr>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That's amazing!
Thank you very much! But in fact my function to do sum it's wrong, I want to display every number side by side, separated by comma ",".
Would you mind to change this?

Comment: @Akilleks, I have updated my answer. It does use an array, just pushes the IDs to the array then joins them on the output to display with a comma.

Comment: That's brilliant! thank you very very much.
I'm in such a hurry and couldn't understand how to do it, this solution it's beyond perfection.